# Xcode 13 doesn't show quick help when option click user defined property, function, etc

Tags: ios, xcode

A quick question. I use to see the inferred type by option click the property or object on the left of a statement. After upgrade to Xcode 13, for instance, when I option click on below `text` property, there is no quick help popping up. Do u guys meet this same issue? Just Google it, no clue found.

```
let text = "Have a nice day"
```

Quick help is only shown when I option-click on an iOS built-in property, function, etc. It doesn't appear for custom defined things.

For code below, when I optional click on `viewDidLoad` or `addSubview` , I could get quick help menu popped up. But without luck for `tableView`, which is a user defined stuff.

```
private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return table
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
}
```

Comment: This seems like an Xcode bug, have you reported it?

Comment: Ok, after restart my Mac, this problem is solved!

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, yeah, I just go to Apple developer forum, I found several similar bugs, a dude said restart the computer fixed it, so that is it. It seems I had not restarted my Mac since the day I upgrade to Xcode 13.

Answer (score 1):

Well, restart your Mac will solve this problem.  It seems I had not restarted my Mac since the day I upgrade to Xcode 13.

The issue link in Apple forum: [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691234)

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the Mac, cleaning build folder and derived data + quitting Xcode didn't help.
Seems like it works only on small projects, but not on the one for the company I work for. It's pretty random and extremely annoying, no idea what could fix it honestly